# Order list where ordering parameter is embedded in list item

Tags: c#, list, linq

I wish to order a list (descending number format) where the list items are strings in the format: n:text (n is a count of text contained within a source list that I built earlier), e.g:

```
5:word1
10:word2
124:word3
```

Output should be:

```
124:word3
10:word2
5:word1
```

Code so far:

```
newList.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.Split(':')[0]));
```

When I run, the list is unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [OrderByDescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netcore-3.1) to have the integers sort from highest to lowest. Also, the function doesn't modify your list, it returns a sequence which you can then convert to a list:

```
var sorted = newList.OrderByDescending(i => int.Parse(i.Split(':')[0])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

`OrderBy` does not change the order of your list but rather returns a `IEnumerable<T>` that is ordered. If you want to save it into your `newList` you could do:

```
newList = newList.OrderByDescending(i => int.Parse(i.Split(':')[0])).ToList();
```